# Can JSP file return a json object for a ajax call?

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

I want to call a jsp file to return a json object to my ajax call. is it possible?
if it is possible, could you please share some example code of both the jsp file and jquery ajax code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will be the content of json from where it should come? is it some data from database? If it is, then use servlet instead of jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Lots and lots of example is in web , guess you are Little lazy in searching let me share an example, And i am using a servlet for the server side

**Create a bean,**

```
public class Countries {     
 public Countries(String code,String name)
        {      
          this.setCode(code);
          this.setName(name);
        }     
 public Countries() {}   

    private String code;
    private String name;           

 public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
 }
 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 }    
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }    
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
```

And **DAO** class to add the data from the database or even hardcode the data,

```
ArrayList<Countries> countryList = new ArrayList<Countries>();
while(rs.next()) { 
             Countries country=new Countries();
             country.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
             country.setName(rs.getString("Name")); 
             countryList.add(country);
            }
```

After that create a **servlet** , which gets the data from the DAO and sends it to the JSP ,

```
ArrayList<Countries> country=new ArrayList<Countries>();
  country=FetchData.getAllCountries();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(country, new TypeToken<List<Countries>>() {}.getType());

  JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);  
 }
```

And finally a **JSP** to view ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tablediv").hide();
     $("#showTable").click(function(event){
           $.get('PopulateTable',function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#countrytable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#countrytable");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                     var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['code']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['name']); 

                });
                }
            });
            $("#tablediv").show();          
  });      
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show Table" id="showTable"/>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="countrytable"> 
    <tr> 
        <th scope="col">Code</th> 
        <th scope="col">Name</th> 

    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thank you for your code sharing. But I mean how can a jsp file return a json without actually calling the Servlet or other external Java api.